# сохранение строки подключения к БД в XML файл и ее вывод

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

Пробую работать с разными базами данных, только учусь

Суть такова, есть 2 БД (Postgre, SQL Server) и мне нужно для каждой БД создать строку подключения и сохранить данные в XML файл.
Есть класс

```
public class ConnectionString
    {         
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public string PWD { get; set; }
        public string TypeDb { get; set; }

        public ConnectionString() { }

        public ConnectionString(string userId, string host, string database, string pwd, string typedb)
        {           
            UserId = userId;
            Host = host;
            Database = database;
            PWD = pwd;
            TypeDb = typedb;
        }
    }
```

который будет использоваться для ввода данных.
Есть форма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию кнопки в файл сохраняются данные с textbox'ов и выбранной базы данных в combobox'e

```
private void createBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionString = new ConnectionString() { UserId = useridTextBox.Text, Host = hostTextBox.Text, Database = databaseTextBox.Text, PWD = pwdTextBox.Text, TypeDb = comboBox1.Text };
            SaveFile(connectionString, "DataConnection.xml");
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

И Теперь сам вопрос, как мне сохранить данные для разных БД в один XML-файл и потом на соответствующей форме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при выборе в combobox'e нужной БД в textbox подтягивалась соотвестсвующая строка подключения.
Пока сделал так

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loadData = LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");           
            if (comboBox1.Text == "Postgre")
            {
                constringTextBox.Text = String.Format("User Id={0};Host={1};Database={2};PWD={3}", loadData.UserId, loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.PWD);
            }
            if (comboBox1.Text == "SQL Server")
            {
                constringTextBox.Text = String.Format("Data Source={1};Initial Catalog={2};User ID={0};PWD={3}", loadData.UserId, loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.PWD);
            }
        }
```

но вот не разберусь как сохранить в одном файле разные строки подключения для двух БД, и соответственно их считать при выборе нужной БД

Comment: [Строки подключения и файлы конфигурации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Comment: @Bulson хорошо, это считывание файла по ключу, я так понимаю, а как мне сохранять данные в файл, так чтобы если я хочу изменить какие-то данные в строке подключения, файл перезаписывался и менял данные только по той базе, которую я выберу в combobox'e?